# Drag'n drop in WPF blocks explorer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop

In my WPF app I'm accepting drag'n drop files, and after checking if they are what I want on input, I'm opening a popup window for the user to input all the necessary info regarding the dropped files. I'm using only the file name from the drop event.

My application is working without any problems. However, I've noticed that when I drop the files, Windows explorer becomes unresponsive and if I'm hovering the mouse pointer over it, I get a "dragging" mouse pointer until the popup window in my application is closed again.

I'm on win 10 if it's important. How can I fix that?

XAML:

```
 <Grid AllowDrop="True" Drop="Grid_Drop"> ... </Grid>
```

XAML.CS:

```
private void Grid_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        var files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            // ... Check if file is acceptable and if so, open window
            ShowCreateEditWindow(file);                       
        }
    }
}

private void ShowCreateEditWindow(string filePath)
{
    var win2 = new CreateEditWindow();
    win2.DataContext = this;
    win2.CreateEdit.Title = "Adding entry";
    win2.fileLabel.Content = filePath;
    if (win2.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        // If everything is ok, do other stuff
    }
    else return;
}
```

Comment: I use Winforms and have added this line:

    `FindForm().Activate();`

(it would be in your `ShowCreateEditWindow` method)

It activates the containing form in case Explorer is waiting. I'm afraid I don't know the equivalent in WPF.

Comment: There is .Activate() regarding windows in WPF, however it didn't change anything, in this case.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question so it is more understandable. I had the same issue (see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it using the approach below:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        this.timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        this.timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        this.timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.dropData != null) {
            ProcessDropData(this.dropData);
            this.dropData = null;
        }
    }

    private void Window_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) {
            this.dropData = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        }
    }

    private void ProcessDropData(object data)
    {
        string[] paths = (string[])data;
        // do work here
    }

    private DispatcherTimer timer;
    private object dropData;
}
```

Using a `DispatcherTimer` allows to process the data at a later point in the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks, it works:)
Still, I feel like we shouldn't have to go such lenghts as to have eventhandler just for watching if other eventhandler fired.

Comment: @Pumar I agree. A developer would expect that this kind of problem is handled by the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`win2.Show()` instead of `win2.ShowDialog`, ShowDialog creates a blocking window. This means you can't use

```
if (win2.ShowDialog() == true)
```

anymore. You probably should replace it with some event system.

Comment: But I do want for this window to block my main window. I just want the filename and then to send to Explorer info that it can go it's way, I've got it covered.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`. This will schedule your delegate to run on the next idle period of the UI thread. This means the drag and drop operation will finish first, and explorer will not be locked.